# Swift dispatch_group strange behaviour on recursive function calling

Tags: ios, swift, recursion, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I'm downloading a bunch of images and executing a callback **after all of them are downloaded**. In order to do this, I'm using `dispatch_group` API.

Because the cache library I'm using has some bugs (they ain't fixing it anytime soon, changing is not an option) I'm segmenting operations in batches (50 images, then 50 other images).

The behaviour goes wrong when I add the recursive call:

```
dispatch_group_notify(downloadGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

    // This works perfectly, get called ONCE after ALL images are downloaded    
    // finishedCallback?(images: images, errors: errors)


    // This snippet doesn't work. I don't understand why but it gets called
    // MULTIPLE times instead of once, like the like above
    if (index + maxDownloadsPerRequest) >= Int(total) {
        finishedCallback?(images: images, errors: errors)
    } else {
        self.callMyselfRecursively(#updatedIndex: index)
    }
}
```

Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try barrier:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("custom_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
  // download image here
});

// call this line when you started all workers
dispatch_barrier_sync(queue, ^{
  // do something then all workers finished
});
```

Comment: If all your code is inside **func A()**,  and I call recursively **self.A()** inside the block ** dispatch_barrier_sync**,  then the function doesn't execute properly, that's the bug I'm having

Comment: So you don't know how much images you need to download and you can't populate queue before dispatch_barrier_sync()?

Comment: No. The problem is I have to download 50 per 50 images, otherwise the library I'm using crashes.  So once the first 50 are downloaded, the next 50 starts.  That's why I'm calling recursively

Comment: Maybe you could provide callMyselfRecursively() function?